# What statistical design and analysis is appropriate for this single-arm study?

Tags: experiment-design, sample-size, random-allocation, research-design

I have research to perform but I am not very familiar with statistical design and the relevant analysis that I have to do, but here is the idea of what I want to do:

It is a single-arm study, I have a group of patients and I want to test if a specific treatment device is working on them or not:

1. The device will be turning on and off 4 times (x1,x2,x3,x4) and so this sequence will be randomly created and each patient will receive a separate envelope of these 4 random states of the device
2. Under each state of the device, there are two possible physical conditions that may happen so if, for example, the device is on, we could either observe(=1) that physical condition, or don't (=0)
3. The outcome of interest would be: under each state of the device and given the observed physical condition, could the device detect that physical condition (=1), or not(=0)

Now my questions are:

1. If I am generating a random sequence of 0 and 1 to do the randomization, how can I be sure that I won`t get (1,1,1,1)?
2. What statistical design should I be using?
3. What is the proper statistical analysis for this matter?
4. Does this make sense if I want to test if the device is working properly:  compare the proportion of times when the device was correctly detecting the physical condition to the true detection (True detection: when the device is off, the condition doesn't exist(=0) or when the device is off, the condition exists(=1))
5. Should I be using the sample size formula for single proportions in this case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you are trying to do what is commonly called a cross-over study. Treating data from this kind of design as independent proportions is wrong, as it ignores that data from the same patient is likely correlated. The literature on that should be rather useful. In cross-over studies it's common to only randomize to options that include two 1s and two 0s (i.e. 0011, 0101, 1001, 0110, 1010, 1100), which would avoid the situation of just 0000 or 1111.

Comment: @Björn many thanks for this insight. Just I am a bit lost on the randomization part now. Does this mean that dont have to generate a random sequence but I have to refer to only those combinations you mentioned? Then how can I randomly assign them to each patient? Eavh of them would have a potential 6 options?

Comment: Exactly, for each participant, you could randomly pick on of the 6 options. Alternatives could include using randomization blocks: you would randomly shuffle these 6 options for every 6 participants (or each option twice for 12, or each option 3x for 18 etc.). That has the effect that after every $B \times 6$ participants all possible sequences have occurred.